# RegDeleteKeyA function always returns error code 5

Tags: c, winapi

I first used RegOpenKeyExA to open the registry path and obtained HKEY, and then called RegOpenKeyExA to delete a key under the path, but the deletion always failed and returned an error code 5. My system is win10, I turned off security protection, and tried running the packaged exe file as an administrator, but the same error occurred. Please tell me what's going on. The path I want to delete is the following one.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{A491BE35-4E0E-CA55-6FAB-884163D38558}

HKEY hKey;
LONG regOpenResult = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
LONG regDeleteResult = RegDeleteKeyA(hKey, "{A491BE35-4E0E-CA55-6FAB-884163D38558}");
```

I tried to execute the program, hoping that the program could delete the data in the registry path, but the program returned error code 5

Comment: Is the code compiled using the same architecture as the operating system? Which call fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (`RegOpenKeyExA` or `RegDeleteKeyA`)? Does the key to be deleted contain any subkeys? Besides, is there a reason for not calling into the wide-character APIs (`RegOpenKeyExW` and `RegDeleteKeyW`)?

Comment: I think wee need a [mcve] here.

Comment: Calling the RegDeleteKeyA function shows ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, but I have solved it now. It turns out that the subkeys were not deleted before deleting this item.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer for the benefit of others. That makes the system understand that the question has been answered, so it can suggeste it to others who ask the esame question.

Answer (score 2):

`RegDeleteKeyA` fails to execute and returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` because there are still data items in the path that have not been deleted. You need to delete the child items first before you can delete the parent item.